# React App doesn't refresh on changes using Docker-Compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Consider the Docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    command: npm start
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    command: npm start
    environment:
      - PORT=3001
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://api_mongo:27017
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/usr/app/src
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"

  api_mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: api_mongo
    volumes:
      - mongodb_api:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      
volumes: 
    mongodb_api:
```

And the React Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:14.10.1-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . .
```

Folder Structure :
-frontend
-backend
-docker-compose.yml

And inside Frontend :

[image]

And inside src :

[image]

When I change files inside `src` it doesn't reflect on the Docker side.

How can we fix this ?

Comment: Are you saying that when you rebuild your docker image, the changes aren't showing? 
Docker won't automatically rebuild when you make changes.

Comment: @RobBailey: Not when rebuilding , meaning while running docker-compose , rebuilding it.

Comment: are you running `docker-compose up --build --no-cache`?

Comment: @RobBailey: `docker-compose up --build --no-cache` doesn't work , I'm running `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: I think it may be because you're storing a copy of the app in a volume. Try removing the     volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/app

Comment: @RobBailey: Doesn't work ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228620/discussion-between-rob-bailey-and-jan).

Comment: @RobBailey: Take a look at my answer , works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the answer](https://github.com/StephenGrider/docker-react/issues/3#issuecomment-508946730) :

> If you are running on Windows, please read this: Create-React-App has some issues detecting when files get changed on Windows based machines. To fix this, please do the following:

1. In the root project directory, create a file called .env
2. Add the following text to the file and save it: CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
3. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same name dir for different services like you use /usr/app change this to /client/app for client and server/app for backend and then it all works and use environment:- CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true and use FROM node:16.5.0-alpine and can use stdin_open: true